# How to parse a plist?

Tags: python, plist

I am trying to parse a plist `pl` below, am able to parse the keys in `["IOKitPersonalities"]["UART"]["ProductFWMapping"]` however am NOT able to print the corresponding `Firmware` values and running into below error?how do I print all the Firmware values,I have the expected output aswell below?

```
pl = {'IOKitPersonalities': {'UART': {'ProductFWMapping': {'D321': {'Firmware': 'C-4377__s-B2/aladdink.trx'}, 'J318': {'Firmware': 'C-4377__s-B2/monstrob.trx'}, 'D331': {'Firmware': 'C-4377__s-B2/geniek.trx'}}}}, 'NSHumanReadableCopyright': u'Copyright \xa9 2013 Company Inc. All rights reserved.'}


for hw in pl["IOKitPersonalities"]["UART"]["ProductFWMapping"]:
    print hw

for hw in pl["IOKitPersonalities"]["UART"]["ProductFWMapping"]:
    print hw['Firmware']
```

Error:-

```
    print hw['Firmware']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Expected output:-

```
['D321','J318','D331']

['C-4377__s-B2/aladdink.trx','C-4377__s-B2/monstrob.trx','C-4377__s-B2/geniek.trx']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hw is just the key. it should be

```
for hw in pl["IOKitPersonalities"]["UART"]["ProductFWMapping"]:
    print pl["IOKitPersonalities"]["UART"]["ProductFWMapping"][hw]['Firmware']
```